# Returning any of multiple CASE statements in one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Unless all `CASE` statements here are True it returns `Null` for the entire `Options` column.
What I cannot figure out is how to return any True `CASE` statments, ie: If Col2,Col4 is not null then return only those values. I have no idea what else to try, help?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Col1 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col1 + '</li>' END +
CASE WHEN Col2 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col2 + '</li>' END +
CASE WHEN Col3 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col3 + '</li>' END +
CASE WHEN Col4 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col4 + '</li>' END Options
FROM TABLE
```

Again, the issue is unless all `Case` statements are found, it returns Null for the `Options` column.

Comment: The IIF function brings up nicer format (it's a short way for writing case statements) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145994(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Col1 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col1 + '</li>' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN Col2 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col2 + '</li>' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN Col3 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col3 + '</li>' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN Col4 Is Not Null THEN '<li>' + Col4 + '</li>' ELSE '' END Options
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

[What @Pieter said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351321/297408), of course, but there are also

1. [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

   ```
   SELECT
       ISNULL('<li>' + Col1 + '</li>', '') +
       ISNULL('<li>' + Col2 + '</li>', '') +
       ISNULL('<li>' + Col3 + '</li>', '') +
       ISNULL('<li>' + Col4 + '</li>', '') AS Options
   FROM TABLE
   ;
   ```

   and
2. [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

   ```
   SELECT
       COALESCE('<li>' + Col1 + '</li>', '') +
       COALESCE('<li>' + Col2 + '</li>', '') +
       COALESCE('<li>' + Col3 + '</li>', '') +
       COALESCE('<li>' + Col4 + '</li>', '') AS Options
   FROM TABLE
   ;
   ```